# Send an email to multiple receipients without them seeing it was sent to multiple. Not BCC

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I know about BCC, but then I need to send to some other email address, like myself, which looks weird for the receipient.

I want to send one email, to multiple people (not in my contact list), and I want each of them to think I only sent it to them.

E.g, say you want to ask for price quotes. You only want to write one email, but send it to multiple suppliers, and you don't want them to see that you sent the same email to anyone else.

Comment: You can use Mail Merge: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bdae0d5c-fb65-420b-97ad-c444b5904d67/sending-emails-to-multiple-recipients?forum=outlook

Answer (score 0):

The method to use in Outlook is the Mail Merge.

You may read about it in the Outlook Help or in the following reference.
In case of a problem, search for it on the internet,
where much documentation can be found.

See for example the article
[Send Same Email to Multiple Recipients Separately Outlook](https://verifybee.com/send-same-email-to-multiple-recipients-separately-outlook/).

Comment: This seems to require the receipients to be in the contact list. Whenever I need this feature, I only want to simply paste the email addresses without creating contacts. Edited original post.
Anyway, I take it that there really doesn't exists any easy way to do this, which I find very strange...

Answer (score 0):

In order to do it in bulk you will need to create some kind of contact list somewhere. Just cut and paste your email list into a csv file is my suggestion, so you can upload. Depending on the number of emails you need to send in one go, and number of contacts you have, you can use CRM software or email automation for free. If it is a basic email my suggestion is Insightly or something similar- there are lots of CRMs that offer free trials or free versions, and it is simple to figure out how to use them. https://support.insight.ly/hc/en-us/articles/204706720-How-to-create-a-new-email-template.

There is no native way (that I know of) to do this in Outlook without creating contacts. If you use another software to send the email you'll not have your contacts saved in outlook, if you want to avoid that for whatever reason. If you don't mind sending it to recipients one at a time you can create email templates in outlook too. https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-an-email-message-template-43ec7142-4dd0-4351-8727-bd0977b6b2d1